# What makes the Disable Device button unclickable?

Tags: touchpad, device-manager

I wanted to disable the trackpad but the Disable Device button is unclickable:

[image]

I then installed its driver and I can disable it via the driver, but the button from the native Device Manager of Windows is still unclickable.

Do you know why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why is that, but in the end I unplug the cable of the touchpad altogether.